# Javascript/Jquery: determine if user scrolls with mouse wheel or scrollbar or keyboard

Tags: jquery, scroll

I'm trying to get a user interface to work, and I need to have it scroll one way if they are using the mouse wheel, and another way if they are using the scrollbar, and another way if they are using a keyboard. I believe scroll wheel and the scroll bar both act as mouse events, but I haven't been able to get javascript to work when clicking on the scrollbar.

Answer (score 1):

Mouse events over the scrollbar vary widely between browsers and aren't something you can rely on. I did a few tests and here's what I found:

- Firefox fires all events (mouse down, move and up) correctly over the scrollbar, even when dragging the bar.
- IE6 fires mouse down but not up, and fires move events only when **not** dragging the bar.
- Chrome (hence I assume Safari too) fires **only** mouse down events.

I should add that I don't see any situation where you would want to do what you describe, i.e. react in different ways to scrolling.