# React onWheel detect if event happened on scrollbar

Tags: javascript, reactjs, scroll

Is it possible to detect in an `onWheel` event if the event happened on a scrollbar? Considering that scrollbars probably have different width/height on each platform/os?

```
function isOnScrollbar(e) {
  // how do I implement this?
  return false
}

class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  @autobind onWheel(e) {
    if(!isOnScrollbar(e)) {
       e.preventDefault()
       // we are inside the content area, do application specific logic
    } else {
       // we are on a scrollbar, keep standard scrolling behaviour
    }
  }

  render() {
    const containerStyle = { width: 300, height: 300, overflow: 'scroll' }
    const contentStyle = { width: 500, height: 500 }
    return <div style={containerStyle} onWheel={this.onWheel}>
      <div style={contentStyle}>Content</div>
    </div>
  }
}
```

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4290307/javascript-jquery-determine-if-user-scrolls-with-mouse-wheel-or-scrollbar-or-ke

Comment: @alt I don't care about keyboard events, only thing I'm trying to do is determine if the actuall mouse wheel event happened on the scrollbar or not.